# Can't display images from a URL

Tags: android, image, url

With `Android Studio` I have a code that displays `images` from a direct `URL`.
I want that displays all the `images` from a site (they are item called `<enclosure/>`) and put that in my `Custom ListView`. So I get the `String` of the `URLs` where is present the `image` and then show it by the code below but I get nothing. Can you help me?

```
TextView txtImage = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
    txtImage.setText(web.get(position).getEnclosure());
    txtImage.setTypeface(myTypeface);

    ImageView img = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.enclosure);

    try {
        URL url = new URL(context.getString(R.id.item_image));
        HttpGet httpRequest = null;

        httpRequest = new HttpGet(url.toURI());

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient
                .execute(httpRequest);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        BufferedHttpEntity b_entity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
        InputStream input = b_entity.getContent();

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all you need to do:

```
URL url = new URL("http://image10.bizrate-images.com/resize?sq=60&uid=2216744464");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

It's not recommended to do this on the UI thread, as it blocks, but you can do it in an AsyncTask.

Comment: I don't need this. I need to download all the images that are in a site. I'm building an RSS app so I want to display the images

Comment: That's a scraper, something completely different from what you're asking.  You'd have to go through and find all `<img>` tags in the HTML and download them individually.  That's really not what your question is asking at all.

Comment: Check my edited answer and let me know if you have understood what I want to do

Comment: That's a completely different question.  You have to go through and grab every image URL you want and display it using the method I showed here.

Comment: Yore going to need a list of the URLs.. Can you retrieve them?

Comment: No, but could you explain the reason you voted down? I think my question is quite understanding about what I want to do

Comment: @user2675569 I didn't vote you down, but your original question is utterly different from the question you asked, and neither were formulated well or put much effort in.

Comment: In fact then I edited it to explain better what I want to do. Isn't it clear yet?

Comment: No, it's really not.  The answer you want is not the question you're asking at all.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know speak english good and I don't know how to let you understand, I don't know how to change my question or delete it

Comment: You should ask the new question and make it the question you're actually trying to ask - how to download a set of images from the website.  A 2nd question would be how to display a set of images, but that's already been answered.